# Reference on Highest Weight Module of Kac-Moody Algebra

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras

I am trying to understand [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00982). The construction requires the understanding of the following concepts in the representation theory of simple and affine Lie algebras:

- The construction of Verma module for a general (not necessarily integral) highest-weight state;
- The character for these modules (the Weyl-Kac character formula cannot be applied for a generic non-integral highest-weight module);
- BRST reduction of affine Lie algebras;
- Quantum Drinfeld-Sokolov reduction;
- ...

I am looking for some references that explain these concepts or some detailed examples of the construction for simplest cases. I appreciate any comment.

Comment: It would help to clarify here what you mean by the symbol $\mathfrak{u}(n)$.  Aside from that, your screen name seems to imply that you are looking at Kac-Moody theory from the physics viewpoint.    I'm mainly acquainted with some texts taking a more mathematical viewpoint, which might or might not be useful to you:  Kac  *Infinite Dimensional Lie Algebras* (3rd ed., Cambridge, 1990); Moody & Patera *Lie Algebras with Triangular Decompositions* (Wiley-Interscience, 1995); Carter *Lie Algebras of Finite and Affine Type* (Cambridge, 2005).   All treat highest weight modules.

Comment: There is also Kac & Raina *Highest Weight Representations of Infinite-Dimensional Lie Algebras (1987)*.

Comment: @JimHumphreys, Thank you for the references. Are they considering infinite-dimensional highest weight modules as well? I mean modules labeled by a set of complex parameters?

Comment: @July, Thank you for the reference, Does it explore infinite-dimensional highest weight modules as well?

Comment: @QGravity: if by module you mean a vector space acted upon by something like $\mathrm{GL}_{\infty}$ (i.e. in the sense that a $k[G]$-module is the same thing as a rep.), then yes.

Comment: @QGravity: The short answer to your question, as in the usual BGG category for a finite dimensional semisimple Lie algebra, is that for basic facts about Verma modules the highest weight can be arbitrary (having any coordinates in the field such as $\mathbb{C}$).     But for refinements involving "integrable" modules and Weyl-Kac character formula, *integral* weights are essential.  The books mentioned all do this.   (In my 2008 text on the BGG category, I used Jantzen's ideas about separating out the integral part of an arbitrary weight.    But this requires extra notation.)

Comment: @July: I'm less familiar with the treatment in Kac-Raina, which does place the subject more directly into the world of physics.    Note that this 145 page paperback volume of the Kac lectures in Bombay (published in 1987 by World Scientific) does not attempt to cover all possible topics, but may be a useful resource.

Comment: @QGravity: Concerning your edit, I doubt that any of the five books mentioned (all of which I have copies of) is likely to help with the study of finite dimensional simple Lie algebras such as $\mathfrak{u}(n)$.   The books emphasize especially the *affine Lie algebras*, which play a big role in some areas of physics but whose structure and representations are far more complicated than in classical Lie theory.    While there are books about the latter aimed at physics, they say little about arbitrary Verma modules.    But my 2008 book on the BGG category is too algebraic.

Comment: @July, Thank you very much for the comment and the recommendation.

Comment: Dear Professor @JimHumphreys, thank you very much for the very helpful comments and recommendations. My main concern was to understand the algebras constructed in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.00982.pdf . I was looking for a reference to understand the construction of highest-weight modules, BRST reduction of affine Lie algebras, Quantum Drinfeld-Sokolov reduction and ... to understand the above-mentioned paper.

Comment: @QGravity: It would have been useful to include such a comment and link in your original question, since the reference to a finite-dimensional Lie algebra wasn't helpful.    The books mentioned are all rather mathematical, in spite of some mention of physics, so they may not help you much.    But I don't feel close enough to textbooks using physics language and notation, which often differ a lot from what mathematicians use.     Maybe you should restate your question?

Comment: Dear Professor @JimHumphreys, I tried to restate the question. Hopefully, this time it is more transparent. I have learned the basics of representation theory of integrable highest-weight module for semi-simple and affine Lie algebras. However, the representation of a generic case, even for semi-simple Lie algebras are infinite-dimensional and the computation of the character requires a new formula, I guess.

Comment: @QGravity:  Thanks for your more precise formulations.    I don't know the physics setting at all well, but I'm still skeptical about finding a single source which touches on all these issues.   The mathematical theory around Kac-Moody algebras (especially affine Lie algebras) and Verma modules is fairly well developed but may be hard to apply in the VOA setting.    Anyway, it helps to specify when the Lie algebra of interest is itself finite or infinite dimensional, since the latter case is less understood.

Comment: @JimHumphreys The Lie algebra of interest are infinite-dimensional. There is a reference that touches some of these topics: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9210010

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend the book

*Affine Lie Algebras, Weight Multiplicities, and Branching Rules*
by Kass, Moody, Patera, and Slansky.

https://www.ucpress.edu/op.php?isbn=9780520067684

Comment: This is an unusual book, with a second volume I don't have consisting of tables (now rather outmoded by the internet).   The first volume has rather old-fashioned typesetting, in an oversized hardback format, and by now is hard to acquire but may be found in some libraries.    It's #9 in a series *Los Alamos Series in Basic and Applied Sciences*, published in 1990 by U. California Press.     But as my comment above indicates, all books listed involve overkill unless one really wants to study an affine Lie algebra (of infinite dimension) and its representations.

Comment: Yes, it's an unusual book. I loved that book!

Comment: @AndréHenriques Thank you very much for the recommendation.